# Python tkinter frames do not fill parent container using Grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm kind of stuck with this problem. I am trying to build an application with several pages. To that end, I create a main Frame and then I raise the frame I need in each moment. This is the code I wrote until now:

```
class Main(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    main_container = tk.Frame(self)
    main_container.grid(sticky = "nsew")
    main_container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    main_container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    menu_bar = tk.Menu(main_container)
    file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff = 0) 
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Save settings", command = lambda: popupmsg("Not supported yet!"))
    file_menu.add_separator()
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = quit)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file_menu)

    tk.Tk.config(self, menu = menu_bar)

    self.frames = {}

    for fr in (MainPage, GraphsPage, Page2):

        frame = fr(main_container, self)

        self.frames[fr] = frame

        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

    self.show_frame(MainPage)


def show_frame(self, pointer):

    frame = self.frames[pointer]
    frame.tkraise()
```

Then, MainPage, for example is:

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    #Tried this but it doesn't work
    #self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    #self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    #self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
    #self.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)
    #self.rowconfigure(3, weight = 1)

    label = tk.Label(self, text = "Main Page", font = LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Graphs", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphsPage))
    button1.grid(row = 1, sticky = 'nswe')

    button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Page 2", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
    button2.grid(row = 2, sticky = 'nswe')

    button3 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Exit", command = quit)
    button3.grid(row = 3, sticky = 'nswe')
```

(I am not showing GraphsPage and Page 2 for simplicity). Finally, I run the program as:

```
app = Main()
app.geometry("1280x720")
app.mainloop()
```

And I am able to make the buttons fit the entire columns, but the columns do not fit the "1280x720" main container. What am I missing?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: i believe you need to configure the grid in each "page" to expand also, and the overall tk window, otherwise your widgets will only expand into the column, and the column will not expand to fit the window

Comment: I think I tried to do that with:
       self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
       self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
in the constructor of the page, but it doesn't work. I've also tried with self.grid_columnconfigure and the same result.

Comment: I've posted an answer that completely shows what i meant, i had to remove the undefined pages to make it run but the code as posted works as you are asking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you had the right idea in the `MainPage` constructor, but then commented it out, but you missed doing it in the top level `Tk` object:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("ariel", 20) # dont know what you had here

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # this needed to be added
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # as did this

        main_container = tk.Frame(self)
        main_container.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky = "nsew")
        main_container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        main_container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        menu_bar = tk.Menu(main_container)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff = 0) 
        file_menu.add_command(label = "Save settings", command = lambda: popupmsg("Not supported yet!"))
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = quit)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file_menu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu = menu_bar)

        self.frames = {}

        for fr in (MainPage,):
            frame = fr(main_container, self)
            self.frames[fr] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, pointer):
        frame = self.frames[pointer]
        frame.tkraise()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # uncommented these lines
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight = 1)

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Main Page", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Graphs", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphsPage))
        button1.grid(row = 1, sticky = 'nswe')

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Page 2", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 2, sticky = 'nswe')

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Exit", command = quit)
        button3.grid(row = 3, sticky = 'nswe')

app = Main()
app.geometry("1280x720")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: OMG, thank you very much. I really appreciate it. I was really stuck at this....
Definitely I was missing self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) and self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) at Main initialisation.

Thanks again for the time you took to answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, the reason why the GUI was not filling the entire window is because `main_container` (your main Tkinter object) has not been assigned a weight. In Tkinter, [weight](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html#resize) describes how much a row or column will grow if there is extra space. By default, everything in Tkinter has a weight of 0 so nothing gets resized unless you modify stuff.